# How to insert image and date in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post, insert

```
if(isset($_POST['post-submit'])){

    $post_category_id = $_POST['post_category_id'];
    $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
    $post_author = $_POST['post_author']; 
    $post_tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
    $post_status = $_POST['post_status'];

    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
    // SQL Injection
    $post_content = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $post_content );

    $post_date = date('d-m-y');
    $post_comment_count = 4;

    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['temp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../img/blog/$post_image" );

    $query  = "INSERT INTO posts(post_image,post_date,post_comment_count, post_category_id, post_title, post_author, post_tags, post_status, post_content) " ;
    $query .= "VALUES('$post_image', now(), '$post_comment_count' ,'$post_category_id','$post_title','$post_author','$post_tags','$post_status','$post_content')";

    $insert_all_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(!$insert_all_post_query) {
      die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));   
    } else {
      echo "<h2>Data Sucessfully Updated</h2>";
    }
}
```

Notice: Undefined index: temp_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms_admin\admin\postCreate.php on line 35

getting this error - but post is getting inseted perfectly

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the code where your error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

you are using function now() in column place

you should write column name for example `created_at`
and if you want current timestamp value in `values` write there now()

Comment: Hi buddy, i have updated the code and getting this error ,please help me out

Comment: <div class="form-group">
        <label for="temp_name" >Feature Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" >
              </div>

Comment: you are really awsome man. it works , but the problem is image is not getting uploaded in the directory, only values getting stored in database

Comment: write that instead of your code move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../img/blog/" . basename($post_image) );

Comment: John Deo is correct you should use tmp_name not temp_name